# i want to display value from database in codeigniter but i am getting errror

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display a value in view in `CodeIgniter` but I am getting several errors like trying to get the property on non-object. I think my code is correct but I am getting errors. Below is my code.

**controller:**

```
public function trainer($id)
{

            $user_record = $this->db->query("select * from usr_data where usr_id=$id")->result();
            $data['title'] = 'trainer Dashboard';
            $data['user_record'] = null;
            $data['active_courses'] = [];
             $data['inprogress'] = [];



            if(count($user_record)) {
                $user_record = $user_record[0];
                $data['title'] = ucwords($user_record->firstname).' Dashboard';
                $data['user_record'] = $user_record;




                $active_courses = $this->base_model->getTrainercourseAll($id);
                $data['active_courses'] = $active_courses;


                $inprogress = $this->base_model->getstaffinprogress($id);
                $data['inprogress'] = $inprogress;

      }
    $this->load->view('trainer-dashboard', $data);
  }
```

**model:**

```
 public function getstaffinprogress($user_id) {

           $result=$this->executeSelectQuery("select AVG(m.percentage) from object_data o, ut_lp_marks m where o.obj_id=m.obj_id and o.type='crs' and m.status=1 ");    
    return $result;
   }
```

view:

```
<h3>Avg inprogress:<?php echo "<span style='color:#ff00ff;font-family:verdana;'>".$inprogress->percentage."</span>";?></h3>
```

I want to display the column percentage which is coming from database.above code is in the controller, model and view.i thought my controller code is wrong.

Anyone help me to get rid of this error. I want to display a value in view in `CodeIgniter` but I am getting several errors like trying to get the property on non-object. I think my code is correct but I am getting errors. Below is my code.

Comment: Where is executeSelectQuery?

Comment: hi thanks for reply.in model i wrote  $result=$this->executeSelectQuery();

Comment: am getting Message: Trying to get property of non-object

this error

Comment: Are you loading your base_model anywhere?

Comment: yes in controller.

Comment: You should update your question to show the line number of the error. I shouldn't have to guess. Even better would be to show the complete error.

Comment: Is user_record actually an array? Should you be doing this: `$user_record['firstname']`

Comment: $inprogress = $this->base_model->getstaffinprogress($id);
                $data['inprogress'] = $inprogress;

Comment: I don't think I can help you. You need to follow the path of code execution, and debug your variables at certain points so you know what's going on. You might consider FirePHP or ChromePHP to make this easier for yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your view file,

```
if(isset($inprogress)){
        echo  $inprogress->percentage;
}
```

Then your code look like this,

```
<h3>Avg inprogress:<?php  if(isset($inprogress)){ echo "<span style='color:#ff00ff;font-family:verdana;'>".$inprogress->percentage."</span>";}?></h3>
```

Then call the controller function. I think inprogress is not set at the first time.

If it doesn't work, try to var_dump($inprogress) in controller and check value and type.

And try this code in your model. Query also seems not correct

```
 public function getstaffinprogress($user_id) {

     $this->db->select_avg('ut_lp_marks.percentage'); 
     $this->db->where('ut_lp_marks.obj_id', $user_id);
     $this->db->where('object_data.type', 'crs');
     $this->db->where('ut_lp_marks.status', 1);
     $this->db->join('object_data', 'object_data.obj_id = ut_lp_marks.obj_id');
     $query = $this->db->get('ut_lp_marks'); 

     return $query->result_array();
}
```

I assume that your db is ut_lp_marks. Then var_dump array and check data is correct first. Then access array element.

Comment: hi bro it didnt worked.i tried with var_dump..i get like this object(stdClass)[22]
  public 'AVG(m.percentage)' => string '0.0000' (length=6)

Comment: I think query is wrong in model. See my updated answer

Comment: now am getting this error bro after using your query   :Message: Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: views/trainer-dashboard.php

Comment: array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'percentage' => null

Comment: the value is 0.

Comment: You have to work on until you see correct output. I don't know what is your db in config/database.php file. And user id is passed to function correctly. Then you have to change $data['inprogress'] = $inprogress; to  $data['inprogress'] = $inprogress['percentage']; in controller and in view simply $inprogress withing isset function as mentioned before. its all upto you.. :)

Comment: replace select AVG(m.percentage) from like below then

Comment: select AVG(m.percentage) as percentage from

Comment: Then data['inprogress'] = $inprogress[0]->percentage;

Comment: Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

if i use above line i am geeting error like this

Comment: its working i am getting value but showing warning message  Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'percentage'

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getstaffinprogress($user_id) {
     $result = array();
     $query=$this->db->query("select AVG(m.percentage) from object_data o, ut_lp_marks m where o.obj_id=m.obj_id and o.type='crs' and m.status=1 ");
     foreach($query->result() as $row){
         $result = $row;
     }
     return $result;
}
```

Also check `$inprogress->percentage` exists before print in view.

Comment: hi bro thanks for reply i used ur code..but i am getting error like thisMessage: Undefined property: stdClass::$percentage